# Is it possible to produce light waves using electronic oscillators or other devices?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, acceleration, charge, oscillators

Radio waves can be generated using oscillating current. And I am wondering whether it is possible to change the properties of current to produce shorter wavelengths *like light waves* or not.

I'm not asking about the possibility of doing this practically. But rather whether it is theoritically possible or impossible.

Please answer briefly and directly to the point - is that possible or not?

Comment: Of course it is possible. But conventionally, would require a very small antenna (in the same order of the wavelength).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Radio antenna producing waves in the visible spectrum](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74892/)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. There are hundreds of facilities all over the world called synchrotron radiation sources where electromagnetic radiation with different wavelengths (ranging from IR to hard X-rays) is produced by circulating electric currents. However, I would not call them antennas.