# If we had a radio antenna produce visible light?

Tags: visible-light, antennas

If we had a radio antenna produce visible light would it degrade the quality of the antenna due  to the light production.

How fast would be the degradation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Radio antenna producing waves in the visible spectrum](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74892/)

Comment: @JohnRennie yes, especially the answer there which recommends heating the antenna :-)